# Is it a good idea to implement delete confirmation in ADF using Task Flows?

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to implement delete confirmation dialog in Oracle ADF using a Taskflow which opens a popup dialog  with OK and Cancel buttons.

If OK pressed "commit" operation happens and if Cancel pressed "rollback" operation happened.

Is it a good idea to implement delete confirmation in ADF using Task Flows?

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way to do it using clientListener with javascript confirm which is faster and does the same thing.

Comment: You will have problem with styling of this window and you will have to call server listeners to implement some special actions. So it may be not easer nor faster way to do it.

Comment: I agree with Nagh. + Using JS can also mess up your DOM so I would use ADF functionality instead.

Comment: @Nagh Thanks for the clarification, yes he'll not be able to be styles but it'll be all client side which is far faster, it's a trade off.

Comment: Of course JS doesn't call any DOM it modifies the existing one. In this case it will probably won't affect your DOM in a bad way cause you will only add stuff to it. It becomes 'dangerous' when trying to hide/make visible existing items.

Comment: @User404 exactly which I'm not doing at all, I'm just presenting a confirm message, if Javascript was dangerous, ADF wouldn't introduce ADF Javascript APIs to manipulate, the fact that the APIs exist, meaning you can use Javascript as long as you follow the recommendations in the APIs

Answer (score 0):

We can implement delete operation confirmation dialog using af:dialog like the following example : Oracle ADF Code Corner-Example 77

But I want to implemet this using ADF Task flows which are more readable.

After creating a task flow like [this](http://postimg.org/image/66czavqgt/) , I could Implement delete operation confirmation dialog like [this](http://postimg.org/image/nnh35zr99/).

Comment: mm.. do I get you right, you want to have confirmation as an existing taskflow step? Or you want it as separate independent taskflow?